# Laravel multi auth

Tags: laravel, authentication

With Laravel multi auth I have made an admin and in AdminLoginController I used the guest middleware not to allow log in as admin when logged in as user. But when I try to log in as user (same middleware in default LoginController) when logged in as admin, the login form comes up and allows me to be logged in as admin and user at the same time. How can I solve this?

Comment: you will want to create a middleware specifically for admin, and in the AdminController (or possibly in the routes) you add that middleware read the laravel middlewre docs it will help you understand how the middleware behaves.